# Connection works on localhost but I can't connect to server from other pc SIgnalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unity-game-engine, signalr

I'm trying to make an unity app with connection client-server-client. This is my server:

```
    class Program
{
  static IDisposable SignalR;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        string url = "http://localhost:8089";
        //string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088";

        SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);

     Console.ReadKey();
  }

  public class Startup
  {
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
     }
  }

  [HubName("MyHub")]
  public class MyHub : Hub
  {
     public void Send(Guid name, int[] message)
     {
            //bramka - to co dostanie od jednego klienta rozpowie wszytskim
        Console.WriteLine($"message sent from {name.ToString()}: move from {message[0]},{message[1]} to {message[2]},{message[3]}");
       Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
     }
  }
```

}

and this is part of my client:

```
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://HERE IS IP ADDRESS OF SERVER:8089/");
    myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

     connection.Start();
```

Everything works fine if in client i try to connect to my localhost but if server is on other PC, I can't make, a connection with this error:"InvalidOperationException: The connection has not been established."
Does anyone have an idea what can I do to repair that? I'm a newbie in programming and very newbie in signalR.

Comment: What do you mean by "on other PC"? Did you deploy your application on a server using IIS? Or are you just opening the application on a different machine?

Comment: No firewall on the other server blocking that port? Or between your computer and the server?

Comment: I've turned off all firewalls. I'm just opening the application on a different machine.

Comment: Also ensure that web sockets are installed on the server. It is on the Server Manager> Add Roles and Features> Server Roles>Web Server(IIS)> Web Server>Application Development

Comment: By server I mean computer with compiling code from the post, where can I find this options?

Comment: @LukeVillanueva does it can even work in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Use server ip or define dns for server computer so you call domain url instead localhost. 
you can retrieve server ip address by using a code like following.

```
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

Comment: Server isn't even compiling when i'm changing localhost or 127.0.0.1 to IP this addresslist.